# Scheme syntax transformation

Tags: syntax, scheme

I am fairly new to Scheme, and I have been struggling with what I think should be a simple problem.

I am trying to convert something like

`((qty 30) (name "ham"))` to `(sandwich "@qty" 30) (sandwich "@name" "ham")`

Also, this must be dynamic to allow for extra clauses:

`((qty 30) (name "ham") (cheese 'no))`

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define-syntax (make-sandwiches x)
        (syntax-case x ()
            [(_ ((col val)...) ) #``(sandwich #,(format "@,~a" (caar #'((col val)...))) #,(cadar #'((col val)...)))] 
            [(_) "make-sandwiches is bad"]))
```

(make-sandwiches ((qty 30) (name "ham"))) => (param "@#(syntax qty)" 30)

So this is kinda close, but it only translates the first clause, so my idea is using `map` or something similar, but I'm not sure if that is correct either:

```
(define-syntax (make-sandwiches x)
        (syntax-case x ()
            [(_ ((col val)...)) (map (lambda (cv) #``(sandwich #,(format "@,~a" (caar cv)) #,(cadar cv))) #'((col val)...))] 
            [(_) "make-sandwiches is bad"]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really *have to* use a macro? and return *multiple* values? a humble procedure that returns a list will do the trick:

```
(define (make-sandwiches lst)
  (map (lambda (data)
         (list 'sandwich
               (string-append "@" (symbol->string (car data)))
               (cadr data)))
       lst))
```

Or a bit shorter (you seem to be using Racket):

```
(define (make-sandwiches lst)
  (map (lambda (data) `(sandwich ,(format "@~a" (first data)) ,(second data)))
       lst))
```

For example, using the sample input in the question:

```
(make-sandwiches '((qty 30) (name "ham") (cheese 'no)))
=> '((sandwich "@qty" 30) (sandwich "@name" "ham") (sandwich "@cheese" 'no))
```

Comment: the syntax is going to be picked up somewhere later and expects something like 
("customer sandwichs" (sandwich @"qty" 30) (sandwich @"name" "ham"))

Comment: @MikeB that's ok, but my point is: if your input is a list of symbols and your output is also a list of symbols, I don't see the need to use a syntax transformation, a couple of list procedures work fine. Also make sure that you _really_ want to return multiple values, perhaps a list like this will be simpler: '((sandwich "@qty" 30) (sandwich "@name" "ham"))

Comment: I'm not totally sure what I want to return, but if it is multiple values, it will be an unknown amount of values

Comment: @MikeB then return a list. You're overly-overly designing the solution, keep it simple! I just updated my answer with a more general solution, for input lists with an unknown number of elements

Comment: @MikeB I'm 99% sure that that's _not_ what you want. In Scheme, most of the time, when you want to return multiple values you pack them in a list and then process the list on the calling side. Although it _is_ possible to return multiple values using `values`, it'll be a hassle on the calling side - for starters you'll have to use `let-values` to unpack them, and then again that won't work because you don't know how many values there will be. Believe me, a _list_ is the way to go here - just iterate over the results in the list.

Comment: @MikeB As you said you're fairly new to Scheme, and you should adapt your way of thinking to the way things are done in this language. For comparison, in other programming language (you name it), how would you handle an unknown number of return values?

Comment: Óscar has good advice. Two relatively special features of Scheme are macros and multiple values. So as you learn Scheme, it's understandable to want to use them. However, that doesn't mean they're the right tool for every job. :)